# How can I extract specific fields from the square Catalog API return object?

Tags: php, catalog, square

I want to access specific fields out of the return object that the Square Catalog API returns using their PHP SDK.  I am using the listCatalog option and it returns the entire object that shows all of the items and all of the corresponding values with it.  However, what do I need to do to break it down further in order to pull out certain values such as name and id?

I have tried different methods to drill down into the object and extract the fields such as:

```php
$id = $result->getObjects()->getId()
```

However, this crashes the program.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```php
$api_instance = new SquareConnect\Api\CatalogApi();
$cursor = ""; // string | The pagination cursor returned in the                                                                               previous response. Leave unset for an initial request. See [Pagination].    (/basics/api101/pagination) for more information.
$types = "Item,Item_Variation,Category"; // string | An optional case-insensitive, comma-separated list of object types to retrieve, for example `ITEM,ITEM_VARIATION,CATEGORY,IMAGE`.  The legal values are taken from the [CatalogObjectType](#type-catalogobjecttype) enumeration, namely `ITEM`, `ITEM_VARIATION`, `CATEGORY`, `DISCOUNT`, `TAX`, `MODIFIER`, `MODIFIER_LIST`, or `IMAGE`.

try {
    $result = $api_instance->listCatalog($cursor, $types);
    $id = $result->getObjects();
    print_r ($id);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling CatalogApi->listCatalog: ', $e-         >getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listCatalog()` function returns an array of `CatalogObject`, so you need to iterate over all the objects returned like this:

```
try {
   $result = $api_instance->listCatalog($cursor, $types);

   foreach ($result->getObjects() as $catalogObject) {
       // Here are all the getter functions you can use to access the data: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Model/CatalogObject.php#L101

       print_r($catalogObject->getId());
       print_r($catalogObject);
   } 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling CatalogApi->listCatalog: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```